# How to turn off DELL BIOS beeping through Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, bios

I removed my LCD with Inverter, because it was broken. I'm using a Inspiron 4050 with a HDMI or VGA connected at TV, but the BIOS beeps(8times) continuos for ever and ever.

There is a way to control the beep volume or mute it through Ubuntu?

Comment: This should have nothing to do with Ubuntu, it is controlled by the BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

If Ubuntu is doing it, then [the above answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65882/22222) is good. But "no monitor chipset" is a Dell BIOS beep code output.

> 8  Video memory read/write error.  Missing or faulty video adapter.

Put in a cheap video card, maybe, the on-board chipset may be broken. You don't have to attach a monitor.

Failing that, physically detaching the PC speaker inside the case is a reasonable option.

Answer (score 0):

The sound is most likely produced by the `pcspkr` kernel module. You can try unloading and/or blacklisting it:

> There are several ways to disable usually noisy PC speaker in Ubuntu Linux (this is what beeps every time you wish to keep silent). The fastest one is just to unload its kernel module/driver:
>
> sudo modprobe -r pcspkr
>
> Add the the line “blacklist pcspkr” to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist to turn off the speaker forever

source: http://www.linuxscrew.com/2009/03/17/the-fastest-way-to-disable-pc-speaker-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Not if it is being produced by the bios.  That module lets the *kernel* make beeps.